# How to check if a post is published today?

Tags: posts

How to show something if a post is published today?

Like this:

```
The Post. _new_  
The Post. _old_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_the_time()` to get the date of the current post. Just use a format that only includes the year and date, and compare it to the current date using the `current_time()` function with the same format:

```
if ( get_the_time( 'Yd' ) === current_time( 'Yd' ) ) {
    // Post was published today.
}
```

Comment: Edited your answer to use [`current_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_time/) instead of `date()`, otherwise you'll have a mismatch if server and wordpress timezone are different